# Unfair duplicate label

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

With regard to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646096/calculating-int-0-infty-frac-sin2xx2dx-using-the-residue-theorem/646113#646113) which was labeled a duplicate, I wish to understand how to best register my disagreement with that labeling.  The alleged original question asks for a short proof of the result, while the current question asks for a particular derivation which anyone who understands the concept knows is not "short."

Comment: In such cases it is possible to use [Request for Reopen Votes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes). However, if it seems likely that the problem might solicit some longer discussion, it is better to use a separate thread on meta (at least in my opinion). Which is what you just did.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks.

Comment: Ron Gordon: I have tagged this post as ([tag:specific-question]). If your intention was to discuss the issue in general and you have used this question merely as an example, please, remove the tag. (In such case I should also remove or change my answer, since it only relates to the specific question, not to the general issue.)

Comment: I suggest that meta threads like this should have titles like "Erroneous duplicate label" instead of "Unfair duplicate label".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the question has been reopened. (I suppose that it was thanks to your post on meta.)

[Calculating $\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin^2x}{x^2}dx$ using the Residue Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646096/calculating-int-0-infty-frac-sin2xx2dx-using-the-residue-theorem)

Here is also link to [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/646096/timeline) of that question.

(I am posting this so that this question does not remain unanswered.)

Comment: Thanks Martin - maybe it was.  I'm glad to see it reopened.